# Update Column in a table based on column from another table.

Tags: mysql

I want to update a field in a column but based on the column from another table.

I have tried this query but it gives me an error report.

```
     UPDATE a
     SET a.CalculatedColumn = b.CalculatedColumn
     FROM Table1 AS a
     INNER JOIN Table2 AS b
     ON a.CommonField = b.CommonField
     WHERE a.BatchNo = '110';
```

Can anybody please inspect what is wrong there and how to fix that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is

```
 UPDATE Table1 a
 join Table2 b ON a.CommonField = b.CommonField
 SET a.CalculatedColumn = b.CalculatedColumn
 WHERE a.BatchNo = '110';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE Table1
 INNER JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.CommonField = Table2.CommonField
 SET Table1.CalculatedColumn = Table2.CalculatedColumn
 WHERE Table1.BatchNo = '110';
```